# How can I add a comment to a LabVIEW file using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system, labview

I am trying to create a unique id and attach it to a LabVIEW file so that later I can read back that id and know I am looking at exactly the same file. I must be able to generate the id and read it back programmatically. The information must be hidden from the user accessing the file and persist across operating systems and storage mediums.

I was thinking of just adding it into the file 'comment' section, but it appears the Windows no longer supports file comments.

Any ideas?

Comment: The standard way of checking whether two files are identical is to compare a [hash](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/hashlib.html) of each one. If you can privately store a copy of the hash of file x at time t1 then you can later calculate the hash at time t2, compare it with the stored copy and see if the file has changed. Does that fit your use case, or do you have some other requirement? Please expand your question with more detail on what you want to do and why.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Let me elaborate on my use case...

These files are exam files. The student is given a file containing  the starting point, then completes the project and submits the updated file. Unfortunately that would change the MD5.
What we are trying to prevent is one student "sharing" the answers and multiple students turning it in. Hence the serial number idea and the hidden from the user requirement. If they don't know it's there, they will be less likely to tamper with it,

Comment: Do you have access to the [VI Analyzer](https://learn.ni.com/center-of-excellence/resources/162/learning-vi-analyzer)? You might be able write an analysis VI that scans the front panel or block diagram for hidden free labels or comments. And you can use [VI Scripting](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/lvhowto/scripting_adding_objects/) to create and hide the label or comment.

Comment: @nekomatic: By default, LV VIs contain compiled code. A slightly different LV version or a slightly different version of an addon, and LV recompiles the VI, which changes the file.

Comment: Many thanks for the ideas. This sounds like an interesting option. I'll look into it. I'm not the LabVIEW guy, he sits at the desk next to me. I'm the coding geek he went to to solve his problem.  However, if there are comments inside a LabVIEW file that can be accessed from an external 'API', then I CAN get there! LV versions don't create any real problem since the file will be generated only a few days away from it's completion and return. The instructor will just need to make sure every student is on the current version before they begin the exam.

Comment: @sweber Before the asker explained their use case, I was expecting this to be something to do with operating in a regulated environment where you need to show that a test or operation is performed with exactly the software it was validated with - in that case even a version difference might count as 'different', so you might want the strict checking that a file hash would give you. The requirement here is not quite the same, as it turns out.

Comment: @Arana is Python 3 actually a hard requirement here, or can you use an all-LabVIEW solution as Joe Friedrichsen suggests? If so can I suggest editing the title so it's not 'Python3' specific?

Comment: nekomatic, python 3 was included as a requirement only because it is my language of choice and simple enough to be maintained by any faculty that aren't programmers. However, you are quite correct that this thread could and should be opened a bit wider for 'posterity'  and that it would be cleaner to create this with an "all LabVIEW" solution. I'll substitute programmatically for "using Python 3"...

Comment: You could also do simple (but easy to crack) trick. Each VI will have record in Properties -> Revision History; for each student - different record (student's ID, or something). This should be set from LabVIEW, b/c I'm not sure whether it is possible to use Python and VI Server together. Then, if you will read VI file from Python as text, you could find that plain text there. If text is not found - it's another student's VI. It's easy to see that text from LabVIEW also, but I'm not sure that students are going to check Revisions History...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [**Set Tag**](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvscript/generic_tag058set_tag/) method on the VI (with persistence) and saving multiple copies of the VI using the Save Instrument method, where each copy would then have its own unique value of the tag. Note that the method is defined as a scripting method, so you would probably need to enable scripting in the LV options to access it.

I don't think there's any API for enumerating tags, so there would be no way to find the value unless you know what the tag is called. Obviously, it's encoded somewhere in the VI file itself, and presumably it would be possible to extract a list of tags if you know the structure of the file, but that's not knowledge I would expect most students to have.

I'm not sure if you can call the set tag method from Python using an external connection to VI server, but certainly the LV code for this should be pretty simple - basically a for loop with ID generation, a couple of method calls and saving a CSV file so you can keep track of which ID belongs to which student. If you use existing IDs, you don't even need to generate and save the IDs.

Comment: TestScript might be a useful LabVIEW/Python connector here, as it's bidirectional: https://www.winemantech.com/testscript-download